# Buscar un elemento de lista a partir de una posición asignada en Python

Tags: python, lista, busqueda

Supongamos que tengo la lista num:

```
num = ['1', '3', '4', '7', '1']
```

Deseo encontrar en esta lista el segundo numero 1.

Si utilizo `"in"` y guardo el valor de índice me devuelve sólo el índice de la primer 1. Omitiendo eso quiero buscar el segundo 1 a partir de la segunda posición de la lista sin tener que hacer una sublista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La lista donde vamos a buscar el segundo '2'

```
num=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '2', '4']
```

Ahora construimos una lista con los indices de los elementos iguales a '2':

```
indices = [i for i in range(len(num)) if num[i] == '2']
```

El indice del segundo '2' esta en `indices[1]`

```
print(indices[1])
```

produce:

```
7
```

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro si pones el número "1" como ejemplo, o porque realmente quieres buscar ese número en concreto.

Si sabes el número que buscar, la respuesta de [Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe) es perfecta.

Si lo que quieres es **buscar el primer duplicado en una secuencia y devolver el índice del segundo** aquí te dejo dos ejemplos para hacerlo y vamos a compararlos, para ello vamos a partir de esta base:

```
lista_test = list(range(10_000))
lista_test.append(9_999) #Repito el último número
```

### Usando listas

Esto es lo que has intentado hacer, usando `in`, si lo creamos bien se puede conseguir. Para ello tenemos que crear una lista inicial y añadir números hasta que haya un duplicado.

```
def duplicado_lista(lista):
    duplicados = []
    
    #con enumerate obtenemos el indice y el número
    for idx , num in enumerate(lista):
        if num not in duplicados:
            duplicados.append(num)
        else:
            return idx
    return "No hay valores repetidos"

duplicado_lista(lista_test)
```

**Salida:** `10000`

Este método tiene un problema y es que necesitas iterar muchas veces, sobre todo con el `in`, ya que **cada vez que tiene que comprobar en una lista, tiene que iterar por todos sus elementos**. Lo que hace que sea cada vez más lento conforme más grande es la lista y más lejos está el repetido. Vamos a testarlo.

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit("duplicado_lista(lista_test)", globals=globals(), number=100)
```

**Salida:** `31.672730094000144`

### Usando set

En este caso el ejemplo es el mismo, pero cambiamos `list` por `set`

```
def duplicado_set(lista):
    duplicados = set()

    for idx, num in enumerate(lista):
        if num not in duplicados:
            duplicados.add(num)
        else:
            return idx
    return "No hay valores repetidos"

duplicado_set(lista_test)
```

**Salida**: `10000`

En los `set` la palabra reservada `in` funciona distinto, ya no tiene que iterar sobre el `set`, ya que este tipo de almacenamiento de datos, utiliza [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Es decir ejecutando una [función hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) encuentra el resultado. Esto es mucho más rápido, vamos a hacer la misma prueba

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit("duplicado_set(lista_test)", globals=globals(), number=100)
```

**Salida:** `0.08859661099995719`

Los `set` son ligeramente más lentos a la hora de [iterar y añadir valores](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) que las listas, pero son **increíblemente rápidos** cuando toca buscar elementos

### Conclusiones

Ambos métodos funcionan a la hora de resolver el problema. La diferencia es que los `set` se adaptan perfectamente a problemas con duplicados, como viene en la [documentación de Pyhon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#set-types-set-frozenset)

> Set Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations

Mientras que las listas no están hechas para este tipo de problemas [documentación listas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#lists)

> Lists are mutable sequences, typically used to store collections of homogeneous items (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by application).